# MySQL Benchmarking, Pre-Production

Tags: mysql, database, performance, phpmyadmin, benchmarking

Is there a way to benchmark SQL queries while in the development phase of a project?

The table in question only has a few sample rows in it, but I'd like to benchmark some queries before the number of rows reaches thousands, millions, billions, trillions, gazillions, whatever...

Is the only option to populate the table with thousands of rows of sample data?

I know very little (nothing) about benchmarking SQL, so detailed = better!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only option to populate the table with thousands of rows of sample data?

Yes.

> detailed = better

Nothing more can be said.  You need full volumes of data.

Comment: Is there some sort of tool for this, or should I just code my own?